# Gmail API insert message add additional "Received" header and shows insertion time instead of received time

Tags: java, gmail, gmail-api

Him
When I inserting message into the Gmail using it's RESTFul api, I load the message from the *rfc822* *MimeMessage*, this message contains original *"Received"*header, that for example has value *Thu, 27 Feb 2014 19:57:07 -0800 (PST)*. When this message inserted into the Gmail, a new "Received" header is added and it has the date time stamp of the time when it was inserted and original header is not shown in the UI, it's presented in the email, but its value is not used to show when the message was inserted. Is there any way to change this behaviour ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting the "internalDateSource" query parameter to the value "dateHeader" on the insert request yet? By default it uses "receivedTime" which would cause the functionality you describe.

[image]
Here is the link for reference. The information your looking for can be found under the "Parameters" header: 
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/insert

---

Once I changed the code to set internalDateSource = "dateHeader" the messages original date value was displayed in the user's Gmail mailbox instead of the time the server received the message. I tested by using the **before:** command in the search bar of the user's mailbox to make sure it worked.

[image]

Here is a list of commands:

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190

FWIW, I'm using the .NET Client API wrapper for the Gmail API, so I'm not making the REST calls directly. However, setting the property in .NET relating to this value seems to do the trick for me. Hopefully this works out for you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is by design, even for mail received through normal channels.
Consider that the headers can be faked, for example, I can craft an email that shows it was sent a year ago and send it to you now. Would you want to rely on the (potentially fake or incorrect) headers, or the actual time it was received, when looking at your inbox? So what you are really asking is to change the time an email was received by Google's server, the public GMail API does not expose that functionality.

It is not so bad though, the search for old imported emails uses the sent date header and not the received date header, so you can still filter by time range.

Comment: The Gmail IMAP behaviour is different :) they use a timestamp header form the message you add to IMAP store. So, at least I'm expecting consistent behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The additional Received header is benign.  What you're talking about is whether the message's internal date is based on the Date header or the current timestamp.  As you noticed, presently it always uses the current time and doesn't allow using Date.

Are you using messages.insert or messages.import (or something else like messages.send)?

For messages.insert and messages.import (only to the current mailbox) allowing the internal date to be the "Date" header seems like a reasonable option.  Not for something like messages.send though given the potential to forge, etc.

Comment: I'm tried to use both insert and import and both works in the same way (regarding the timestamp). And if you can provide an option to use message's header timestamp instead of current it'll be great. Thanks